# How To Index Range Of 2-D Numpy Array From Different Start Points Sourced From Other Array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am attempting to extract out and perform math on the subset of one numpy array that is of shape (3,32), the subset of data I am attempting to extract out is that of shape (3,9) and the ranges of this data originate at the indices contained in another array size (3). As an example, I have a data set of values from three channels operating in the time domain and I extract the index of the max value of each channel into an array

```py
a = np.random.randint(20,size = (3,32))
a
array([[18,  3, 10,  6, 12,  1, 10,  8,  4, 11, 13, 14,  9,  9, 10,  2,
         9,  0,  0, 16, 14, 19,  1, 19, 14, 19, 19,  2, 14,  0,  4, 18],
       [ 9, 19,  2, 12,  0, 14, 18,  7,  3,  0,  7,  3, 12, 19,  4,  2,
         5,  9,  2, 11, 15, 19, 16, 17,  3,  4, 17,  5,  6,  1,  2, 17],
       [ 0, 11, 18,  8,  9,  2,  9, 15,  9,  6,  0,  8,  9, 16,  9,  6,
         1, 19,  1,  9, 12,  8,  0,  0,  7, 15,  3, 14, 15,  8, 10, 19]])
b = np.argmax(a,1)
b
array([21,  1, 17], dtype=int64)
```

my goal at this point is to derive a new array consisting of the three values from each of the indexes specified.  For instance I would be looking to extract out :

```py
[21,22,23] from a[0]
[1,2,3] from a[1]
[17,18,19] from a[2]
```

all into a new array of size [3,3]

I've been able to achieve this using loops already but I suspect that there is a more efficient way of producing this result without loops (speed is a bit of an issue with this application).  I have been able to effect a similar result by manually populating a smaller matrix manually ...

```py
c = np.asarray([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
a[np.arange(3)[:,None],c]
array([[ 3, 10,  6],
       [ 2, 12,  0],
       [ 8,  9,  2]])
```

However, given the dynamic nature of this application I would like to write this such that it can be dynamically scaled (range of indeces out to 9 values beyond the root index, etc).  I just don't know if there is such a way to do this.  I have used syntax similar to the following in an effort to slice the array ...

```py
a[np.arange(3)[:,None],b[:]:(b[:] + 2)]
```

resulting in error messages in the nature of ...

```py
builtins.TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: What if there aren't 3 values remaining in the row in `a`?  For example, what if the max was at index `31`?

Comment: Yeah I considered that I should stipulate that, the range will never exceed the bounds of the array given the nature of the application (in the actual application the max indices always are 10 +/- 1)

Comment: In the accepted solution, use `b` as `idx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you cannot overflow, this gets much less tricky.  In general, since you have your starting indices, you can use basic broadcasting to create an `(n, 3)` shape array with your indices, and use `take_along_axis` to pull those elements from the original array.

---

```
np.take_along_axis(a, b[:, None] + np.arange(3), axis=1)
```

```
array([[19,  1, 19],
       [19,  2, 12],
       [19,  1,  9]])
```